# angular-ui/ui-router, how do I inject partial view using $stateProvider?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am trying to inject a panel for editing, depending if the viewer is the owner, or not. Right now, I am having trouble just injecting the panel/partial view into the html. I want my compositions/views/view.html to be the 'base' html page, where the partial is injected in. Then the partial view is at compositions/views/partials/views.tools.html. Does anybody see something wrong with my $stateProvider that would explain why I cannot inject my partial into my views.html?

Here is my $stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('all compositions', {
            url: '/compositions/recent',
            templateUrl: 'compositions/views/list.html'
        }). 
          state('view', {
                url: '/compositions/view/:compositionId',
                views: {
                'theTool':{
                 templateUrl:'compositions/views/partials/view.tool.html'   ,
                    controller: 'CompositionsController'
                }
                },
                templateUrl: 'compositions/views/view.html',
                controller: 'CompositionsController',

            }). //other states here
```

this is my markup for my view.html (main html)

```
<div ui-view="theTool"></div>
<section data-ng-controller="CompositionsController" data-ng-init="findOne()">
    <h2>{{composition.title}}</h2>
    <div ng-bind-html="trustedContent"></div>
</section>
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what error you getting in the console?

Comment: I would start by cleaning up this double templateUrl and controller in the view called 'view.'

Comment: A directive that conditionally showed the editor panel would probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here I created a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YJklNEMygHdH6zcgMYHP?p=preview), which should give all the answers.

The adjusted state defintion is:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('allCompositions', {
    url: '/compositions/recent',
    templateUrl: 'compositions.views.list.html'
  }).

state('view', {
  url: '/compositions/view/:compositionId',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'compositions.views.view.html',
      controller: 'CompositionsController',
    },
    'theTool@view': {
      templateUrl: 'compositions.views.partials.view.tool.html',
      controller: 'CompositionsController'
    }
  },
```

the most important is, that the `compositions.views.view.html` is now playing the role of a target for the *sibling* view `theTool`. both views are defined on the same state ('view') but one of them is injected into the other.

Also in the index.html I did this change:

```
<!--<div ui-view="theTool"></div>-->
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

so now we do have ***unnamed*** ui-view instead of the named. That's why both states

- allCompostions
- view

which target unnamed view '' are now properly rendered. Se more here in this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YJklNEMygHdH6zcgMYHP?p=preview)

More about the the view insertion logic:

- [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

small cite:

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.

Awesome examples from the same source:

```
.state('contacts.detail', {
  views: {
    ////////////////////////////////////
    // Relative Targeting             //
    // Targets parent state ui-view's //
    ////////////////////////////////////

    // Relatively targets the 'detail' view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
    // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html
    "detail" : { },            

    // Relatively targets the unnamed view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
    // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html
    "" : { }, 

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Absolute Targeting using '@'                      //
    // Targets any view within this state or an ancestor //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Absolutely targets the 'info' view in this state, 'contacts.detail'.
    // <div ui-view='info'/> within contacts.detail.html
    "info@contacts.detail" : { }

    // Absolutely targets the 'detail' view in the 'contacts' state.
    // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html
    "detail@contacts" : { }

    // Absolutely targets the unnamed view in parent 'contacts' state.
    // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html
    "@contacts" : { }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed problem and quick feedback. This was helpful, but I am still confused on a couple of things. Why did you change the templateUrl path to '.' instead of '/'? I am getting redirected whenever I go to /compositions/view/15 back to /compositions/recent, which is strange because I didn't add a redirect. I saw the config on plunker and didn't include it..

Comment: Hard to say what is causing the redirect... but the plunker is working, so try to use parts of that... and your local stuff should work. What is recent? If you extend the question and I will be ble to help...

Comment: Okay! It works! Thank you SOO Much!!! It is amazing. The problem with the redirect was that I was getting a 404 error with my main template. I was trying to rename some files and I deleted it. After I restored it, it worked.

Comment: Awesome! Good luck with `ui-router`, amazing tool ;)