# Using AngularJS to replace the HTML of one div

Tags: angularjs

Using jQuery, it's easy to replace the innerHtml of a single div, either with content from the elsewhere in the HTML, from a JavaScript var, or from an HTTP call.

How can I do that in AngularJS (without using jQuery)? For example, to keep a page the same, but only replace a side panel?

Comment: potential solutions: ngInclude, implement your own directive, or use something like ui-router

Comment: Have a look at the routing in AngularJS: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-view / ui-router . More details :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

[angular-ui/ui-router, how do I inject partial view using $stateProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902365/angular-ui-ui-router-how-do-i-inject-partial-view-using-stateprovider)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer is: "Think twice if you need to do this."  In Angular, the paradigm isn't to *modify* the HTML, but rather to *bind* the HTML.  So, bind the div's src to a scope or controller var via ngInclude, and just change that var.